# WhatsApp Backup from low storage phone: How can I keep my old media and back up new chats at the same time?

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, whatsapp.app

I’m kinda lost on the following topic:

My iPhone 11 got stolen a couple months back and I had everything in iCloud including WhatsApp chats. When I started using another phone with only 64GB capacity, WhatsApp kept telling me that there’s **not enough space to back up current chats and restore my media (see screenshot)**.

[image]

[image]

I ignored that for the whole time as I knew I’d buy a new phone soon. I just got the iPhone 14 Pro with enough storage. However my problem now is, that I would like to keep both media from before that hasn’t been able to load due to lack of storage AND the new chats that were created in the past months with the other phone. I needed to free up 40 GB for my media to be recovered and now I’ve tried deleting literally every single app, got rid of all the photos on the phone by turning off iCloud synching and I still need to free up 12 GB.

**Is there any way I can guarantee getting both my media and the recent chats?**

Can I skip media restore for now in order to back up current chats and then get that media back once I use WhatsApp on the new phone?

Can I delete anything else?

Weirdly my phone is showing me that it still uses 4GB for Photos even though there aren’t any. I’m not sure if I’m missing some hack that would free up more space. I’m adding a bunch of screenshots here so you get an idea.

Thank you so much in advance

[image]

[image]